# Register custom Filter via Factory

Tags: php, zend-framework, filter, zend-framework3, zend-inputfilter

I am trying to register my custom filter and use in **getInputFilter()** method, but constantly getting the error:

> A plugin by the name "myCustomFilter" was not found in the plugin manager
>   ZendFilterFilterPluginManager

```
$inputFilter = new \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
$inputFilter->add([
    'name'       => 'inputname',
    'required'   => true,
    'filters'    => [
        [
            'name' => 'myCustomFilter'
        ]
    ],
]);
```

And register it in module.config.php

```
return [
    'filters' => [
        'aliases'   => [
            'myCustomFilter' => Test\Filter\MyCustomFilter::class,
        ],
        'factories' => [
            Test\Filter\MyCustomFilter::class => Test\Filter\MyCustomFilterFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Also in application.config.php I registered

```
'modules' => [
    ...
    'Zend\Filter',
    'Zend\InputFilter',
    'Zend\Validator',
 ],
```

Note that I am using ZF3, so is there anything else to setup/configure?

I can use the filter without the factory but create filter via factory is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating an instance of InputFilter we need to update the default FilterManager

```
$inputFilter->getFactory()->getDefaultFilterChain()->setPluginManager(
    $container->getServiceLocator()->get('FilterManager')
);
```

*Of course it's better to inject "FilterManager" this is only a test code.*

Answer (score 0):

Do you load the `Zend\InputFilter` in your `modules.config.php` https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/config/modules.config.php

Like this :

```
return [
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\InputFilter',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Application',
];
```

Comment: In your module.config.php, have you tried to replace 'filters' >> 'input_filters'

Comment: yes I try it :) ... for these 2 days I tried everything .. I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible - to register filter via factory

Comment: I found this >> https://gist.github.com/basselin/a704e77934a131235140ae83c1d8eee4